# Kann "haben" ein Hilfsverb für Passiv sein?

Tags: passive, rules

Ich lese jetzt "Amokläufer" von Stefan Zweig. [Es gibt dort](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=vjN8DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA10&lpg=PA10&dq=%22wenn%20man%20**geholfen%20haben**%20will,%20darf%20man%20nicht%20herumreden%20und%20nichts%20verschweigen%22&source=bl&ots=vBcXX_lJfs&sig=ACfU3U0Xdk7P4IP1AIb-lkfZT_DCMQLVjA&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjA_Ji-r7PgAhWIxosKHWLODsgQ6AEwBXoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=geholfen%20haben%20will&f=false) so ein Satz:

"...wenn man **geholfen haben** will, darf man nicht herumreden und nichts verschweigen..."

Ich dachte immer, dass man für Passiv nur die Hilfsverbe "werden" und "sein" nutzt. Woher ist hier plötzlich "haben" entstanden? Was für ein Regel ist es?

Comment: Nachlesen kann man die Passage auch hier: http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/amok-6860/2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Es handelt sich um ein Passiv, genauer eine seltene Form des sogenannten Dativ- oder Rezipientenpassiv.

## Reguläres Passiv

Ein reguläres Passiv würde mit *werden* und einem transitiven Verb stehen:

> **Er** will untersucht werden.
>   "**Er** will, daß **er** untersucht wird."

Das Besondere hierbei ist, daß *er* sowohl logisches Subjekt von *wollen* als auch von *werden* ist, wie die Umschreibung deutlich machen soll.

Da im Passiv ein Dativobjekt ein Dativobjekt bleibt, ist das Passiv von *helfen* subjektlos und kann nicht mit *wollen* stehen.

> **Ihm** muß geholfen werden. (=**Man** muß **ihm** helfen.)
>   ***Ihm** will geholfen werden.

## Dativpassiv

Es gibt auch ein Dativpassiv (oder Rezipientenpassiv) mit *kriegen* oder *bekommen* plus Partizip II, bei dem das Dativobjekt zum Subjekt wird. Die meisten Sprecher werden allerdings ein Beispiel wie das folgende eher schlecht finden:

> Er **kriegt/bekommt** geholfen.
>   Er will geholfen bekommen/kriegen.
>   "Er will, daß er geholfen bekommt/kriegt."

Dafür sehe ich drei Gründe: Erstens gefällt vielen Sprechern das Dativpassiv an sich nicht; zweitens wird es lieber von dreistelligen Verben wie *schenken* als von zweistelligen wie *helfen* gebildet; drittens ist in diesem Fall *er will Hilfe bekommen* eine naheliegendere und einfachere Variante.

Der zitierte Satz läßt sich analysieren, wenn *haben* hier als Hilfsverb des Dativpassiv gedeutet wird:

> **Ich** will nichts geschenkt **haben**.
>   "**Ich** will nicht, daß **ich** etwas geschenkt **kriege/bekomme**."
>
> Wenn man geholfen haben will...
>   "Wenn man will, daß man geholfen **kriegt/bekommt**..."

Der Unterschied zum normalen Dativpassiv ist, daß man das *wollen* nicht streichen kann, da *haben* plus Partizip II sonst automatisch als Perfekt gedeutet wird.

> Er hat nichts geschenkt. (nur Aktiv, Perfekt)
>   Er kriegt/bekommt nichts geschenkt. (Dativpassiv)

## Mehrdeutigkeit

Die Sätze mit *wollen* plus *haben* plus Partizip II sind mehrdeutig.

> 1) Er will die Sache erklärt haben. (Epistemisches Modalverb plus Perfekt)
>   "Er behauptet, die Sache erklärt zu haben."
>
> 2) Er will die Sache erklärt haben. (Deontisches Modalverb plus Dativpassiv)
>   "Er will, daß er die Sache erklärt bekommt."

Im Kontext des Romans scheint mir klar, daß es um die zweite Variante geht: Der Patient will, daß ihm geholfen wird, und darf deshalb nichts verschweigen.

Comment: "Im Kontext des Romans" ist wichtig, den konnte ich zunächst nicht aufrufen, sodass mir nur der Textschnipsel blieb. Mit einer erneuten Suche im deutschen Google Books wird aber alles klar. Schöne Antwort (bis auf die veraltete Rechtschreibung).

Answer (score 1):

Das ist kein Passiv. Das ist "aktiv". Etwa analog zu Futur II (vollendete Zukunft) nur für Vergangenheit, es gibt bestimmt einen Namen für diese grammatikalische Konstruktion. Die Person ("man" in dem Fall) will nicht, das ihr *geholfen wird*, sondern dass sie selbst *geholfen hat*.

Das ist vielleicht nicht die ausführlichste Antwort auf die Frage, aber ich wollte das gesagt haben.

Comment: Ich denke, dass es falsch ist. Lesen Sie bitte manche Sätze neben diesem Satz im Buch. Es geht darum, dass dieser Mann geholfen werden will, aber es ist geschrieben auf solche seltsame Weise.

Comment: Ehrlich gesagt, ich weiß nicht, worum es geht. Meine Antwort basiert auf der Zitat in der Frage und nicht auf den manchen anderen Sätzen im Buch. Wenn diese anderen Sätze wichtig sind, dann sollten sie auch in der Frage zitiert sein.

Comment: Ohne Kontext hätte ich zugestimmt, aber aus dem Kontext wird klar, wie der Autor den Satz verstanden haben will (huch, noch ein Adressatenpassiv mit *haben*).

Comment: Ich hab' darum ein Link hinzugefügt, um den Kontext zu zeigen.

Comment: @EndreBoth +1 für "verstanden haben will")))

Comment: @P.Vowk Der Link öffnet mir eine Seite irgendwo im Buch, der zitierte Text ist dort nicht markiert, d.h. es ist nicht klar, ob es überhaupt die richtige Seite ist.

Comment: @Eller man sollte ja ein bisschen suchen, ich hab' es schon repariert.

Comment: Auch ohne Kontext _kann_ der zitierte Satz passiv sein. Die Antwort, dass es sich nicht um Passiv handelt, ist also falsch.

Answer (score -2):

*"Ich denke, dass es falsch ist."* - Nein, P. Vowk, Ellers Antwort ist die einzig richtige hier.

Sieh dir Folgendes an:

> Er **hat** jemandem **geholfen**. -> Wenn er jemandem geholfen hat, ...
>
> Man **hat** jemandem **geholfen**. -> Wenn man jemandem geholfen hat, ...
>
> Man **will** jemandem **geholfen haben**.  *Man will* = man behauptet / man bildet sich ein, jemandem geholfen zu haben
>
> -> **Wenn man jemandem geholfen haben will,** ... (wenn man behauptet / sich einbildet, man habe / hätte jemandem geholfen)

Von Passiv weit und breit keine Spur. ;-)

Die Antwort auf deine Frage im Betreff lautet unabhängig vom deinem Beispielsatz, der kein Passiv enthält: Nein, *haben* kann kein Hilfsverb in der Passivkonstruktion sein.

Comment: Das ist falsch und ignoriert auch die Antwort von David Vogt. Daher gebe ich hier -1

Comment: _Man will geholfen haben_ lässt sich in der passivischen Bedeutung eben gerade nicht in _Man will jemandem geholfen haben_ übersetzen, sondern in _Man will geholfen bekommen_.

Comment: Ich kopiere mal ein paar Sätze aus dem Kontext:
... Aber Sie verstehen es sonst nicht ... Ich weiß nicht, ob ich je so etwas wie ein guter Mensch gewesen bin, aber ... ich glaube, hilfreich war ich immer ... und ich kriegte es noch fertig, ihn zu retten. Stundenweit bin ich gefahren, wenn irgendein Weib im Fieber lag – auch so wie diese es wollte, habe ich geholfen, schon in Europa drüben an der Klinik.   weil ich ihren Stolz nicht geschont, ihr nicht gleich geholfen hatte ...